# Seleccionar solo un checkbox a la vez dentro de una tabla y obtetiendo los datos de la fila marcada usando jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy intentando solo seleccionar un checkbox a la vez que se encuentra dentro de una table y obtener los datos de la fila. Este es mi table:

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table class="table table-hover table-custom border-radius-total-5 no-margin" id="tablelistaReservas">
    <thead class="backGris-light-be">
      <tr class="s20">
        <th class="no-borders">RESERVACION</th>
        <th class="no-borders">NOMBRE</th>
        <th class="no-borders">LOC_EXTERNO</th>
        <th class="no-borders">PICKUP</th>
        <th class="no-borders">RETURN</th>
        <th class="no-borders">CANAL</th>
        <th class="no-borders">AUTO</th>
        <th class="no-borders"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="backWhite">
      <tr class="s18 colorGrayLight">
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">1</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Pedro Canche Angulo</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">34577567856</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">28/may/2018</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">30/mayo/2018</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Web</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Jetta</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">
          <div class="margin-l-15 checkbox checkboxStyle-table checkColorGreenLight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="tableid" name="tableid" id="tableid" class="click">
            <label class="s18 text-normal"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="s18 colorGrayLight">
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">2</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Pablo Canche Angulo</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">34577567856</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">28/may/2018</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">30/mayo/2018</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Web</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Jetta</td>
        <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">
          <div class="margin-l-15 checkbox checkboxStyle-table checkColorGreenLight">
            <input type="checkbox" class="tableid" name="tableid" id="tableid" class="click">
            <label class="s18 text-normal"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

No he podido realizar dicha funcionalidad. Espero su ayuda con alguno link de como lo puedo hacer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con el evento `change` podemos controlar los cambios de valor de los elementos de formulario, en este caso tus `checkbox`, simplemente vamos a preguntar que cuando un `checkbox` esté activo automáticamente el resto se desactiven y se muestre la información de los elementos correspondientes a la fila a la cual pertenece el `checkbox` activo.

Ahora para capturar dicha información lo que haremos es seleccionar el `tr` al cual pertenece el `checkbox` y luego vamos capturando uno a uno el contenido de cada `td`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            
            var reservacion =$(tr).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
            var nombre = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            var loc_externo = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
            var pickup = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
            var retorno =$(tr).find('td:nth-child(5)').text();
            var canal = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(6)').text();
            var auto = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(7)').text();
             
            console.log('reservacion: ' + reservacion + ' - nombre: ' + nombre + ' - loc_externo: ' + loc_externo + ' - pickup: ' + pickup + ' - retorno: ' + retorno + ' - canal: ' + canal + ' - auto:' + auto);
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-container">
<table class="table table-hover table-custom border-radius-total-5 no-margin" id="tablelistaReservas">
<thead class="backGris-light-be">
    <tr class="s20">
      <th class="no-borders">RESERVACION</th>
      <th class="no-borders">NOMBRE</th>
      <th class="no-borders">LOC_EXTERNO</th>
      <th class="no-borders">PICKUP</th>
      <th class="no-borders">RETURN</th>
      <th class="no-borders">CANAL</th>
      <th class="no-borders">AUTO</th>
      <th class="no-borders"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="backWhite">
  <tr class="s18 colorGrayLight">
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">1</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Pedro Canche Angulo</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">34577567856</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">28/may/2018</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">30/mayo/2018</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Web</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Jetta</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">
    <div class="margin-l-15 checkbox checkboxStyle-table checkColorGreenLight">
      <input type="checkbox" class="tableid" name="tableid" id="tableid" class="click">
      <label class="s18 text-normal"></label>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="s18 colorGrayLight"> 
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">2</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Pablo Canche Angulo</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">34577567856</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">28/may/2018</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">30/mayo/2018</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Web</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Jetta</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">
    <div class="margin-l-15 checkbox checkboxStyle-table checkColorGreenLight">
      <input type="checkbox" class="tableid" name="tableid" id="tableid" class="click">
      <label class="s18 text-normal"></label>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="mensaje"></div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte me funciono totalmente. Saludos.

Comment: @PedroMisaelCancheAngulo me alegra que te haya servido, te invito a considerar marcar la respuesta como aceptada para finalizar la pregunta y que futuros desarrolladores se vean beneficiados con la solución, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Por partes:

1. Tus `checkboxes` deberían tener un `id` único. En este caso tienes los dos con el `id="tableid"`
2. Viendo la etiqueta de la pregunta entiendo que estás utilizando jQuery, ¿no?

En ese caso podrías asignar el evento click a los checkboxes que empiecen por un `id` concreto (por ejemplo "chk_").

3. ¿Qué información de la tabla quieres obtener?

Siguiendo con `jQuery` puedes buscar la fila (`tr`) más cercana al checkbox con el método `closest("tr")`

4. Seleccionar sólo un checkbox:

$("input[id^='chk_']").not(this).prop('checked', false);

Te dejo un ejemplo con todo esto:

```js
$(function(){

$("input[id^='chk_']").on("click",function(){

   $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);

   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
      obtenerFila(this);
   }
});

});

function obtenerFila(ctl)
{
 alert($(ctl.closest("tr")).html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-container">
<table class="table table-hover table-custom border-radius-total-5 no-margin" id="tablelistaReservas">
<thead class="backGris-light-be">
    <tr class="s20">
      <th class="no-borders">RESERVACION</th>
      <th class="no-borders">NOMBRE</th>
      <th class="no-borders">LOC_EXTERNO</th>
      <th class="no-borders">PICKUP</th>
      <th class="no-borders">RETURN</th>
      <th class="no-borders">CANAL</th>
      <th class="no-borders">AUTO</th>
      <th class="no-borders"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="backWhite">
  <tr class="s18 colorGrayLight">
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">1</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Pedro Canche Angulo</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">34577567856</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">28/may/2018</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">30/mayo/2018</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Web</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Jetta</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">
    <div class="margin-l-15 checkbox checkboxStyle-table checkColorGreenLight">
      <input type="checkbox" class="tableid" name="tableid" id="chk_1" class="click">
      <label class="s18 text-normal"></label>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="s18 colorGrayLight"> 
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">2</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Pablo Canche Angulo</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">34577567856</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">28/may/2018</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">30/mayo/2018</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Web</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">Jetta</td>
    <td class="no-pad-top no-pad-bot align-middle">
    <div class="margin-l-15 checkbox checkboxStyle-table checkColorGreenLight">
      <input type="checkbox" class="tableid" name="tableid" id="chk_2" class="click">
      <label class="s18 text-normal"></label>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por explicación. Saludos.